# Alternative to dual list UI Pattern

Tags: tagging, grouped-list

So in my application, a user can select a Widget, and select tags that describe that widget (Fast, Slow, Expensive,i.e).  As of now, the plan was to use a dual-list with a bag of "unchosen" descriptors, and a bag of "chosen" descriptors.  Essentially, my UI currently looks like the [UI discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852995/whats-this-ui-pattern-called).

My issue now is that the user has to be able to select a group of widgets (n > 1) and then apply a descriptor to all of them ("Describle all these widgets as slow").  Clearly, this breaks the UI as the dual list now has to somehow handle Add/Delete operations for (n > 1) widgets.

My next progression was going to be a 3 part list where they would have a first list with

```
"All"

"Widget 1"

"Widget 2"
```

But that felt wrong.  Does anyone know of a UI pattern that can allow the user to perform Add/Delete changes on 1 or more Widget items or am I thinking about this incorrectly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many descriptors do you have?

Answer (score 1):

can the user only add 1 description? Maybe you can then reverse the workflow. Let the user select that descriptive work and then apply it to the widgets in a selection. Like making buckets for descriptions and filling them with the widgets.

Answer (score 0):

The 3-part list is wrong because it will only be 3 parts for a set of 3 widgets. Beyond that you'd have to offer entries for all the possible subsets of your widget list, which is 2 to the power of the number of your widgets minus one (I think... Not good at math :) ).

You can simply add checkboxes to your list of widgets (or provide another way for multiple selection) and let the user select as many as they need, before attaching the tags to the entire selected list.